# Facing issue in code regarding PHP version 5.6 to 7.x

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I'm facing issue in PHP version, when I'm running in 5.6 the code is working well. When changing to 7.x, the code is showing an error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/lib/pages/server.php on line 25

Code:

```
/* select all the weekly tasks from the table googlechart */
$result1 = sql_query($db, "SELECT `date`, `rank` FROM Accounts WHERE `ip` = " . $acc['ip'] . " AND `joined` = " . $acc['joined'] . " GROUP BY `date` DESC");
$rows1 = array();
$table1 = array();
$table1['cols'] = array(
    // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles.
    /*
    note that one column is in "string" format and another one is in "number" format
    as pie chart only required "numbers" for calculating percentage
    and string will be used for Slice title
    */
array(
    'label' => 'date',
    'type' => 'string'
) ,
array(
    'label' => 'rank',
    'type' => 'number'
)
);
// var_dump($result);
/* Extract the information from $result */

foreach($result1 as $r1) {
    $temp1 = array();
    // The following line will be used to slice the Pie chart
    $temp1[] = array(
        'v' => (string)date('m-d ga', strtotime($r1['date']))
    );
    // Values of the each slice
    $temp1[] = array(
        'v' => $r1['rank']
    );
    $rows1[] = array(
        'c' => $temp1
    );
}
$table1['rows'] = $rows1;
// convert data into JSON format
$jsonTable1 = json_encode($table1);
// var_dump($jsonTable);
// echo $jsonTable1;
```

Comment: How does `sql_query` work? Is it backed onto the `mysql_` api by any chance?

Comment: `$result1` is not an array, so your query failed. I'd suggest looking at the code for `sql_query`. It's not a standard function, so it's something that was created.

Comment: I changed to sql_ to mysql_ but not working.. can you please check the query.. I'm thinking have issue in database query @aynber

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Switch your code to use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: Additionally, yes, your query would fail because your variables would need to be quoted: an ip address is considered a string unless you're converting it first, and `joined` is mostly like a date/datetime. Switching your code to use PDO or mysqli and using parameter binding would remove those quoting issues.

Comment: Can you edit and post it here.. or write here for me also I'm getting error regarding "Group by".. @aynber

Comment: Sorry, that goes beyond what I can do right now. Check out the links I posted, they should help.

Comment: You probably have a SQL injection in this code - swap to parameter binding as soon as you can. Meanwhile, we cannot answer this without knowing what `$result1` contains or the actual query you are running. It is a good idea to create a new variable `$sql` containing the SQL query, and then supply that to your database function separately, so it can also be printed to the screen. Once you have done that you can run the query against your database directly, to see if it works, without PHP involved.